# On android 11 status bar doesn't get hide

Tags: android, android-layout

This code makes status bar transparent on Android 10 and before

`//makes actionbar transparent        activity.window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)`

However in android 11 it doesn't disappear

Android 11

[image: This is on android 11]

Android 8

[image: this on android 8]

My styles.xml file look like this

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<style name="DropitTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>


    <style name="MyThemeOverlay_Toolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary">
        <!-- color used by navigation icon and overflow icon -->
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Toolbar_text_style" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
        <!-- color used by navigation icon and overflow icon -->
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/textSizeHuge</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

The manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/DropitTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and last the themes.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.Dropit" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/colorSecondary</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/colorSecondary</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/colorSecondaryLight</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

As you can see in the Manifest I'm using the styles theme not the themes theme. So how can i fix this problem?

Comment: Hi I met the same problem on Android 11. (Emulator Pixel 4 and also a physical device). Would you mind share your `styles.xml` or `themes.xml` file for others who trying to help you?

Comment: Hey @dumbfingers thanks for your response, i added the two files you asked for

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and find out this solution.

```
val controller = requireActivity().window.insetsController
        controller?.systemBarsBehavior = BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
        controller?.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars())
```

If you call it from Activity requireActivity() is not needed.
I had some problems where on some fragments it started to reset to the standard status bar, so I called it on every onCreate() and it fixed it.

Comment: By above code status bar hide and show on swipe but status bar show in dark, how can we make them transparent or same color as app.

Comment: @swati You can set BEHAVIOR_SHOW_BARS_BY_SWIPE or BEHAVIOR_SHOW_BARS_BY_TOUCH, but then you need to hide it manually after the onTouch event.

Answer (score 1):

I've found compatible [sollution](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/edge-to-edge#kotlin) to set nav bar and status bar transparent.
Make sure to **remove** fitsSystemWindow=true in your code if you used it to achieve status bar transparency, otherwise it won't work correctly.

If you want to set only status bar transparent and not nav bar:

1. add

   ```
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
     WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
   }
   ```
2. Set `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>` in
   your app theme
3. Add bottom inset to the main view container. In my case it's
   frameLayout, which displays fragments

   ```
   ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(binding.main_container) {
                                                                      view, windowInsets->
               val insets = windowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())

               view.updateLayoutParams<ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams> {
                   bottomMargin = insets.bottom
               }
               WindowInsetsCompat.CONSUMED
           }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

for **notch display** or **camera inside the screen** this code work for me.
I checked on Redmi note10 :

```
    private fun hideSystemUI() {
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        window.attributes.layoutInDisplayCutoutMode =
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES;
    }
}
```

call this right after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    hideSystemUI()
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    //do you work
}
```

Comment: Those Flags are deprecated on Android 11. The OP asked about Android 11, not Android 10.

Comment: @WachidSusilo I mention above. I Checked on Redmi(Android 11) and this code work for me. I'm sorry for deprecated