# How to properly hide the status bar for Android API 30?

Tags: android

In my Android app, I want to hide the status bar, and the status bar only.

Here is what I did, in my activity, that behaves as expected:

```
// method #1:
window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
```

The problem is: it's deprecated in API 30 (Android 11).

So here is what I tried, for API 30:

```
// method #2:
window.insetsController?.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars())
```

It hides the status bar as expected, but the behavior is different: when I scroll down from the top of the screen to make the status bar appear, not only there is some weird glitch, but more importantly, the status bar doesn't hide after a few seconds, as the previous method allows to do.

So how can I hide the status bar for API 30+, so it hides by itself after a few seconds when I make it appear?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66364430/15298643) ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer (from an Activity):

```
val controller = window.insetsController
controller?.systemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsController.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
controller?.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars())
```